# How can I extrapolate a pattern from a collection of filenames?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, extrapolation

I want to know if there is a well-known algorithm for extrapolating a filename pattern, given a collection of sample filenames as input. Take the following example filenames:

```
  ABC_348093423.csv
i.ABC_348097340.csv
  ABC_348099322.csv
i.GHI_348099324.csv
p.ABC_348101632.csv
  DEF_348101736.csv
p.ABC_348101633.csv
  ABC_348102548.csv
```

Ideally, the patterns that I would want to end up with in the result set would be something like:

```
*.ABC_*.csv
*.DEF_*.csv
*.GHI_*.csv
```

Even result values like the following would still be a good starting point:

```
i.ABC_348*.csv
p.ABC_348*.csv
...
```

**Why do I need this?**

I have an existing application where users can input a "file mask" to define a bucket for incoming input files to be grouped into. Incoming files are evaluated against each file mask (in order), and if the file matches a mask, the file goes into the bucket for that file mask... the end.

What I'd like to implement is, given the last X filenames that were processed, present the user with suggestions for new file masks. **It does not have to be perfect. This will just be a user-assist feature.**

**What language am I using?**

My application is written in Java, so any third-party Java library that can perform this kind of function would be an ideal solution. Otherwise, if there is a well-known algorithm for this problem, then I could implement it myself.

Comment: are you looking for regex-pattern?

Comment: The analysis of strings to discern patterns is almost a mathematical field of its own. There would be no automatic library to compute this.

Comment: off topic : **too broad** and **recommendations for offsite resource**

Comment: Not looking for a REGEX pattern, exactly the opposite. Given a set of inputs, the output would BE a pattern that matches the inputs.

Comment: So you basically want to group the files into clusters and then find a regex pattern that would differentiate the clusters.

Comment: This problem is fundamentally unsolvable unless you have access to the entire set of filenames.  Given a sample of possible filenames you can write a pattern that matches them. However, there's always a probability that the next filename does not match the pattern.  This sounds like an XY problem.  Assuming you were to find such an algorithm, what would you use it for?

Comment: @JimGarrison Edited the description to explain my purpose

Comment: To fully realize what you are hoping for, consider two trivial results of such an algorithm: `.+` and `ABC_348093423.csv|...|ABC_348102548.csv". One is too wide (accepts everything), the other one (presumably) too narrow. You can refine this, looking at varieties of substrings, and, finally, for individual character positions. (Is it `[A-Z]` or  `\p{Lu}`?)

Comment: Is the scope of your problem to find several common substrings from a set of filenames, so that you can construct a simple wildcard pattern from them?

Comment: are the filenames always of this format: <optional-1-letter-followedby-.><3-letter-abbreviation>_<numericalvalue>.csv ?? if so you just need to get a list of the most recent n 3-letter-abbreviations and 'distinct' them. If not... I'm doubtful you can truly do this.

Comment: You might think of other options, such as presenting the user with a large number of recent files, and allowing them to create a mask in-line which will immediately show them what their results would be (displaying match # and total # would be fairly helpful i think).

Comment: @Randyaa - Interesting idea. I'll run that by the UI developer as an alternative to what I was considering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to suggest wildcard patterns based on common substrings, you could use a [longest common substring algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) to calculate all the common substrings, then choose a few based on their length and number of occurrences. This can be done recursively to find even more common substrings.

This example does 2 iterations of a [longest common substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Java) and outputs the results:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    private static String longestCommonSubstring(String S1, String S2)
    {
        int Start = 0;
        int Max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < S1.length(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < S2.length(); j++)
            {
                int x = 0;
                while (S1.charAt(i + x) == S2.charAt(j + x))
                {
                    x++;
                    if (((i + x) >= S1.length()) || ((j + x) >= S2.length())) break;
                }
                if (x > Max)
                {
                    Max = x;
                    Start = i;
                }
            }
        }
        return S1.substring(Start, (Start + Max));
    }



    public static SortedMap<String,Integer> commonSubstrings(List<String> strings) {
        SortedMap<String,Integer> subs = new TreeMap<>();
        for (String str1: strings) {
            for (String str2: strings) {
                if (str1 != str2) {
                    String sub = longestCommonSubstring(str1,str2);
                    if (subs.containsKey(sub))
                        subs.put(sub,subs.get(sub)+1);
                    else
                        subs.put(sub,1);
                }
            }
        }

        return subs;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> filenames = Arrays.asList(
                "ABC_348093423.csv",
                "i.ABC_348097340.csv",
                "ABC_348099322.csv",
                "i.GHI_348099324.csv",
                "p.ABC_348101632.csv",
                "DEF_348101736.csv",
                "p.ABC_348101633.csv",
                "ABC_348102548.csv");

        Map<String,Integer> substrings = commonSubstrings(filenames);

        Map<String,Integer> subsubstrings = commonSubstrings(new ArrayList<>(substrings.keySet()));

        List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>(subsubstrings.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(results, (a,b) -> a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue()));

        for ( Map.Entry<String,Integer> s: results ) {
            System.out.println(s.getKey() + "\t" + s.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this misses shorter substrings common to all the file names such as `.csv`